# ajax POST data results are in the console, but displayed on the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

This problem has not occurred until I figured out it was actually a problem to begin with. I apologize for the confusing question. Basically, I am gathering a mysql id with php and using the POST Method with ajax to try and put that post id into a query. The thing is that the query works and the data shows on the console, but not live on the screen here:

[image: Console Results]

On the screen itself, I don't see anything but array(0){}. Because of the `var_dump`.
It almost seems that maybe it's not updating on the screen, but it is on the console. Here is what my code looks like for the modal:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='small' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog'>
<div class='modal-content'>
    <h3 class="fetchuserid" style='text-align: center;'>
    <?php

        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "testdb");



        $uid = $_POST['postuserid'];
        var_dump($_POST); <-- This is where you should be seeing the array(1){["postuserid"] => string(2) "10"} `10` being the id I clicked.


        $ssql = "SELECT * FROM foodid WHERE postid=$uid";
        $rresult = mysqli_query($db,$ssql);
        while($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult)){

            echo $lrow['countid'];
            echo '<span class="postid_count">'.$lrow['countid'].'</span>'; <-- This is where you should be seeing all of those span in the console.

        }

    ?>
    </h3>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the anchor tag for accessing the modal and responsible for holding the ids:

```
echo '<a  href="#" data-postuserid="'.$row['id'].'" id="smallbtn" name="smallbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#small"  data-modal="small">';
```

And lastly here is my ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','#smallbtn',function(){

        var postuserid = $(this).data('postuserid');
            $post = $(this);
            console.log($(this).data('postuserid'));

        $.ajax({

            url: 'cooking.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'postuserid' : postuserid
            },
             success:function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $post.parent().find('span.postid_count').text(data); <-- Here is what I tried to do to I guess "update" the data from the POST. No success.
             return data; <-- I read other questions and was told to do this. No success.
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
           $( document ).ajaxError(function( event, request, settings )
            {
              $("#banner-message > p").text('Sorry, we are having a trouble in this url "'+settings.url+'!"') 
            });
        }
        });
    });
```

NOTE: This is all happening in one page, there are no refreshes so no data is being lost. I did check my network tab to see if that's the issue and everything was ok with a 200 POST method. It also showed the correct postuserid in network as well as in the console.

I am not sure I am asking the right question here, but any feedback is gladly welcomed! Basically how can I display the result of my query from the ajax post from console and put it on the page?

PEN:  codepen.io/anon/pen/djbgKj

Comment: The first run of your php, it will result in that empty var dump, because no POST argument was passed. Then, when ajax fires off, it passes the POST arg... hm.......... And somehow, this question looks awfully familiar.

Comment: That's correct. Now that you said that. I think php just runs as soon as you enter the page? But then again I am activating the post method before it shows on the modal.

Comment: Is `cooking.php` the same php that generated the original page with the ajax javascript block? Seems an awful lot of html is being returned with that ajax call, when I think you are only wanting the list of spans.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am not sure what you mean there. But most of  HTML was automatically generated from the php queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help you

```
document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = data;
```

please give it a try

in your case you can do this :

```
$post.parent().find('span.postid_count').innerHTML = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not targeting your desired HTML element correctly or it does not exist:

Try:

```
alert( $post.parent().find('span.postid_count').length ); // or use console.log() if you prefer, it doesn't matter
```

And I hope you get alerted with 1 or more. If not then you need to properly target the HTML element within your page.

Additionally use `.html()` instead of `.text()` because `.text()` will strip the HTML code from your `data` string.

```
$post.parent().find('span.postid_count').html(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for mention that. I had no idea what was happening or why. Also, I tried and used both code and got 0 as the result of the alert. This means I am not targeting the HTML element correct? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @LaneyWilliams Correct, `$post.parent().find('span.postid_count')` is returning no matched elements so your your data goes nowhere.

Comment: May I also note that in my Pen, I have the same ajax code but the HTML is different. It updates that amount correctly.

Comment: So what is `$post.parent().find('span.postid_count')` really saying? Is it trying to find the data-userpostid which is the parent and supply the data to the span?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams CodePen does not execute PHP so it's treated as just plain HTML. When you execute your code on your server then you get different HTML. If you are using Google Chrome then run your script and press `ctrl` + `u` and verify if your HTML is exactly what you think it should be.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams `$post.parent().find('span.postid_count')` can be translated to: from the clicked `#smallbtn` find the parent tag and within it search for all instances of `<span class="postid_count">`

Comment: I see. So placement of the html does count?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams It most certainly does.

Comment: Ok ok. In my case is there a solution to that with javascript or do I have to just rearrange my html code?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams Anything is possible but I have no clue what your rendered HTML looks like. Have you tried checking with `ctrl` + `u`?

Comment: Yes. It's a bunch of user html data and the modal has no data except `array(0){}` do you want me to copy all of it to the pen?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams My best guess is that `while($lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult)){` is not being looped so `<span class="postid_count">` is not available.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams No thanks, that's too much code. I am trying to have **you** identify why your HTML is not marked up correctly in relation to your jQuery.

Comment: With **your** eyes I want **you** to find `#smallbtn`, look at the parent tag, and try to figure out what the heck happened to `<span class="postid_count">`

Comment: `span class="postid_count"` is at the bottom my html in a modal. It's parent is `<div class='modal fade'`. And for `#smallbtn` (i think you mean the anchor tag), it's parent is: `<div class="hero">`. These are automatic generated html from the query.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams I see, in theory if you use just `$('span.postid_count').html(data);` then you should see the new HTML. Whether or not this is the correct solution is your problem to solve.

Comment: Same result. Maybe if I use the parent of span? Also, I appreciate all of your work and helping me understand this.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams `$('span.postid_count')` searches through your entire web page. `$('span.postid_count').length` should be showing you 1 or more if your claim that "`<span class="postid_count">` is at the bottom my html in a modal" is accurate. Are you sure the element is not hidden? You can also right-click > Inspect Element to traverse your DOM in real-time.

Comment: Oh what! By hidden do you mean in an echo? Because the span is in an echo. And php code is not visible in the source.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams hidden meaning hidden from your browser either by positioning, `display: none`, or `width:0px`. Try using Inspect Element to traverse your DOM to get an idea of how to formulate your jQuery target. Good luck.

Comment: Right. I know it's not hidden because when I use the get method I can see all of my results in the modal. Thank you, at least I got an understanding of the situation.

Comment: I was accidentally trying to put the whole html code in the span. I wanted to put the result of the query in the span.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams I see, if this answer/conversation helped you the most then feel free to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`$post.parent().find('span.postid_count').text(data);`

To This:

`$post.parent().find('span.postid_count').html(data);`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ok I switched it out and I still get nothing.

Comment: OK, can you please post the entirety of your automatically generated HTML content. It looks like your jQuery selector can't bubble up to find the correct element.

Comment: I believe the modal code above is the generated html content? It is what displays all of those span in console image.

Comment: One huge issue is the initial generation does not create any `span.postid_count` to subsequently replace after ajax returns from a button click. There needs to be a container to swap all the spans out in/out. The only container I see is `h3 class="fetchuserid"`

Comment: So would I use that instead of `span.postid_count`?

Comment: I am talking about the html that surrounds your #smallbtn - as IncredibleHat says it is like this button's parent() does not exist so jQuery cant display it

Comment: Thats another concern, is we don't know where the `id="smallbtn"` element is in relation to anything. And from the looks of it, it is built with a `while` loop variable, and that is also concerning, since `id` must be unique across the entire DOM ...

Comment: Can you view your browser's source and copy that into codepen and link us to it so we can see the entire rendered HTML and verify if the required parent element exists or not

Comment: oh! Sorry about that: echo '<a  href="#" data-postuserid="'.$row['id'].'" id="smallbtn" name="smallbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#small"  data-modal="small">';
     echo '<img style="height: 30px; width: 30px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: -4px; right: -5px;" src="../img/eye_icon.ico">';
     echo '</a>';

Comment: Nope, I need the ENTIRE page's HTML please! You know, if you are using Chrome, then view source, copy and paste... there should be no php code visible!

Comment: I'd love to share the entire source, but I do have sensitive information and it's huge.  The `id="smallbtn"`  is for the javascript in my question. I can share with you specifics of my code if that's alright... @WebCode.ie

Comment: I'm not looking for your raw source.... I am looking for your rendered source as in the "View Source" button in chrome. Copy and paste that into a website called codepen (remove anything sensitive if there is anything there - although there shouldn't be as we are talking about HTML, not PHP) - then paste the link to CodePen - trust me - just trying to help!

Comment: No no I see what you are saying. I apologize. Will do. I just noticed something that may or may not affect it. My anchor tag is alone above my modal. Maybe the parent is suppose to be with what I am trying to display? If that makes sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174673/discussion-between-webcode-ie-and-laney-williams).